# Why do python dictionaries react to the actions performed on another equal dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Sorry for confusing title name, I wasn't quite sure how to word it.
I have the code below:

```
eps = []
newdict = dictionary.items
for ep in range(minepisode, maxepisode + 1):
    eps.append(str(ep))
for key in dictionary.keys():
    if key not in eps:
        newdict.pop(key)
```

However, when I try to run it, it returns with the error,

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

despite the changes were being made to 'newdict' and not 'dictionary', which was the one I was iterating.

After messing around in shell I found that if I made 2 identical dictionary like this:

```
x = {'1':'something'}
newx = x
newx.pop('1')
```

Both the '1' key in x AND newx were removed. Why is this? And how should I fix the error in the original code?

Comment: You are not creating a new dict, just copying the reference to the old dict. Use copy or deepcopy to clone the dict.

Comment: @Selcuk Thanks! Just tried this and now it works

Answer (score 2):

Firstly `dict` in python is `mutable` data structure..

So, it works like this..

```
x = {'1':'something'}
```

So, here `dict` object `x` has been created...

```
newx = x
```

So, here you referred the same `dict` object to another `variable` called `newx`.

Ideally you didn't create a new object, you just referenced the same object to other variable..

You can see that similarity like this..

```
>>> id(x)
140222539383424
>>> id(newx)
140222539383424
```

Id's of both the objects are same...

You can also verify this by using `object similarity` check by using `is`

```
>>> newx is x
True
```

So, for obvious reasons it doesn't matter whether you are trying to change `x` or `newx`, you are changing the same referenced object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change a dict while in loop, you should use `copy.deepcopy()`; it will allocate separate memory for both.

Example:

```
import copy

a = {'key':'value'}
b = copy.deepcody(a)
```

Hopefully it will help you. :)

Comment: cody is very deep

Answer (score 0):

You have a dog, you're an extraordinary person and you call your dog `flash` on even days and `turtle` on odd ones. Today, March 28th, `flash` hurts their front right leg, would you be surprised if tomorrow you'll find that `turtle` too has a wounded front right leg?

Python is like that, you have objects that are permanent and names that you stick on them... some of these objects are *immutable* (e.g., strings) and when you think to modify one of them you're creating a  new object instead, the old object still around, the old labeled by `flash` and the new by `turtle` --- others are *mutable* (e.g., dictionaries) so that a change can be directly applied to the object itself, that is still referred by all their names.

To me, *immutable* objects' behavior is most surprising but I understand I'm a minority... and as such I need preservation.

Disclaimer: no animal was actually hurt in the making of this post.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have a list `colours=['blue','green]`. When you do something like `palette=colours` you make `palette` an alias to `colours`: they both refer to the same list located at the same memory address.

```
colours=['blue','green']
palette=colours
print id(colours)==id(palette) #True
print id(colours[0])==id(palette[0]) #True
```

There is a way to change it. Consider you define `palette=list(colours)`. Now you created a new list that is located at another address in memory. But now both lists contain elements at the same adress: palette[0] and colours[0] are located at the same address.

```
colours=['blue','green']
palette=list(colours)
print id(colours)==id(palette) #False
print id(colours[0])==id(palette[0]) #True
```

Finally, you have deepcopy

```
from copy inport deepcopy
colours=['blue','green']
palette=deepcopy(colours)
print id(colours)==id(palette) #False
print id(colours[0])==id(palette[0]) #False
```